# The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold CAML Query in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

For some reason I am getting threshold while executing below CAML query with Pnp. It works fine when folders have few records in sharepoint. I am using RecursiveAll as library will have sub folders in SharePoint. I tried rowlimit in CAML query and -pagesize with Get-PnPListItem but no luck.  Any help on how I can pass page size.

```
$CAMLQuery = "@<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" + $AppField + "'/><Value Type='Text'>" + $AppNumber + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>"                     
Write-Host "CAM LQuery "$CAMLQuery
$ListItemsToUpdate = Get-PnPListItem -List $List.Title -Query $CAMLQuery
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure below things before using the SharePoint list columns in the filter conditions:

1. Add indexing on the column (whatever `$AppField` you are using) from list settings

   Check this documentation for more details: [Add an index to a list or library column](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0)
2. Make sure you have less than 5000 records which matches the filter condition else you will have to fetch the records in batches

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPListItem](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPListItem.html)